# Error: Redirected when going from "/" to "/dashboard" via a navigation guard

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

For some reason that I don't understand, Vue is raising the following error: `Error: Redirected when going from "/" to "/dashboard" via a navigation guard.`.

I understand where this happens:

```js
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { Route } from "vue-router";

@Component({
  async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    const sites = getUserSite();

    if (sites && sites.length) {
      next();
    } else {
      next("/sites/create");
    }
  }
})
export default class Dashboard extends Vue {}
```

I don't want to let users have access to the /dashboard unless they have at least one site in the database. I have no clue why this is happening. Can someone give me a light?

Comment: Hello there, to me your code looks ok. I've had a similar issue once. I fixed it by just deleting node_modules and the package-lock.json and ran npm install. Maybe it helps.

Comment: could you share the `getUserSite()` function code?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Christoph Dietrich's comment: your code seems ok. The only difference is the place I used to configure the `navigation guard`. I configured it on my `main.js` file, the same place where you configure all the imports and the Vue instance itself:

```
//Import the Vue Router in order to use it
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

//In my case, I import the configuration for each route for aesthetic reasons (it's a huge file)
import Routes from "./utils/routes.js";

//Configure Vue to use the Router
Vue.use(VueRouter);

//Instantiate/Configure the router
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: Routes,
    mode: "hash",
});

//Configure the navigation guard
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    //Note that I'm using a global "beforeEach" navigation guard, 
    //therefore, I have to check if I am coming from the "/" page
    //and I want to go to the "/dashboard:

    if (from.path == "/" && to.path == "/dashboard") {
        const sites = getUserSite();

        if (sites && sites.length) {
            next();
        } else {
            next("/sites/create");
        }
    }
    
});

function getUserSite() {
    ....
}

//Mount the Vue instance with the router:
new Vue({
    render: (h) => h(App),
    router: router,
}).$mount("#app");
```

- Instead of `from.path == "/" && to.path == "/dashboard"`, you could use [Named](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html) routes or [meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html) to verify if the route requires any validation.